# Return value don't return

Tags: c

I wrote a *word_pattern* function as below.

I didn't get a return value, what's wrong with the code?

Below is the *codewars* training.(https://www.codewars.com/kata/5f3142b3a28d9b002ef58f5e/train/c)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> //strlen
#include <ctype.h> //islower

char *word_pattern(const char *word) {
  int i, j;
  int size = strlen(word) ;
  char *ans = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (size * 2 ));

  char *base = ans;

  if (ans == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    if (i == 0)
    {
      *ans++ = (char)i;
      *ans++ = '.';
      /*break;*/ continue;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
      if ( islower(word[i]) == islower(word[j]) )
      {
        *ans++ = (char)j;
        *ans++ = '.';
        break;
      }
    }
    
    if(j == i)
    {
      *ans++ = (char)i;
      *ans++ = '.';
    }
  }

  *--ans = '\0';
  return base;
}
```

Comment: What is `size`?

Comment: The `break;` in `if (i == 0)` terminates the outer `for` loop.  Did you mean to use `continue` instead?

Comment: Are you expecting the return value to be a 0 terminated string? If so, `(char)i` when i is 0 is `'\0` which is the string terminator. So your return value will look like an empty string

Comment: @Merrifield you tag people with `@` and they'll be automatically notified. `>>` does nothing

Comment: @Siguze Sorry for my omission, I've filled it.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler That's right!

Comment: @The Dark I intended to convert numbers to letters.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I didn't get a return value, what's wrong with the code?

Below code sets `ans[0]` to 0, the *null character*.

```
if (i == 0) {
  *ans++ = (char)i;
```

Printing the return pointer as a string prints nothing as the string ends immediately.

Comment: I intended to convert numbers to letters.How can I do that?

Comment: @Merrifield What do you mean by converting numbers to letters? Did you mean converting a number 512 to a string containing 512?

Comment: @Shovo >>Did you mean converting a number 512 to a string containing 512?  Yes.

Comment: @Merrifield I have written a program to do the conversion. you can check the [link](https://pastebin.com/TRiqsYM5) . For better viewing, I have shared through Pastebin

Comment: @Shovo Thank you, but that page is no longer available.

Comment: @Merrifield you can check this [link](https://pastebin.com/UpBU2sJ2)

Comment: @Shovo This time, I used Pastebin for the first time.
I'm logged in, but I get the error message below. why?   "Error, this is a private paste. If this is your private paste, please login to Pastebin first."

Comment: @Merrifield sorry, made a mistake. please check this  now [link](https://pastebin.com/Upy3UAxb)

Comment: @Shovo  Thank you very much.
I was able to see it.
But what is the "cin" in your code?

Comment: @Merrifield, my mistake. Firstly I wrote the code in c++ then converted it into c. you have to use scanf("%d",&num) instead of cin.

Comment: @Shovo Is it okay to add "+'0'"?

Comment: @Merrifield yes, it will convert the digit to character

Comment: @Shovo I got it.